# Declarative SQLAlchemy CREATE SQLITE in memory tables

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, declarative

This is how I setup my database for an application (in Flask):

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = None
db_session = scoped_session(lambda: create_session(bind=engine,
                                                   autoflush=False, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=True))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_engine(uri, **kwargs):
    global engine
    engine = create_engine(uri, **kwargs)

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    return engine
```

If I connect to a file database that has had tables created already, everything works fine, but using **sqlite:///:memory:** as a target database gives me:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: users u'DELETE FROM users' ()
```

when querying like so for ex.:

```
UsersTable.query.delete()
db_session.commit()
```

I am accessing this code from a unit test. What is the problem?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Working setup of the application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'XXX'

# presenters
from presenters.users import users

# register modules (presenters)
app.register_module(users)

# initialize the database
init_engine(db)
```

Comment: What's the output if you add "print Base.metadata.tables.keys()" just before .create_all() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't contain any table/class declaration. Are you sure that the declaration is done before init_engine() is called?

Comment: You are quite right! I have updated the question with the 'correct' order of execution. Thanks @jd